# Drawing using my finger in SpriteKit and swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

i found this code online that does the job but the posted code isn't full so if anyone can help me with the following

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch!
    firstPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch!
    var positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)

    lineNode.removeFromParent()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, nil, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y)
    lineNode.path = pathToDraw
    lineNode.lineWidth = 10.0
    lineNode.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()

    self.addChild(lineNode)
    firstPoint = positionInScene
}
```

what are lineNode and pathToDraw and if you can please show me how to write their code, or redirect me to something that can help.

Comment: `class YourClassName 
{
    var pathToDraw : CGMutablePathRef?
    var lineNode : SKShapeNode ?
..........
........

}
`

Comment: is this solve your problem ? @Daniel Al-Makhamreh